# typeset functions location

Tags: unix, ksh

When I use the command `typeset -f` in `ksh`, a list of functions with their definition is displayed in stdout.
I tried to search where those functions are defined, but I couldn't find any hint about them. Can anyone help me finding them?

**EDIT**

I'm just learning the use of the typeset command, typing `man typeset` game me nothing (`no manual entry for typeset`). 
In order to define functions that will be displayed using `typeset -f`, we need to define a function and export it using `typeset -xf`.

Comment: Where they are *defined?*

Comment: I mean from where typeset -f is fetching them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can be declared in the `.profile`, or files called from `.profile` or put in a dir that is referenced by the FPATH variable (and proabably other places too). Read your `man ksh` carefully for the order of files that are processed on startup. Search for the 'Invocation',  'Files', and 'Functions' sections.

Also, there are a group of default functions that ksh sets up. So please edit your question to show the function names that your concerned with.

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

Shells don't keep a record of where functions (or aliases, or variables, etc...) are defined. Conceptually, and notwithstanding interactive usage features like shell history, shells read commands from input one at a time, execute them, and then forget them. Sometimes those commands come from interactive input, sometimes they come from scripts. Sometimes they have side effects like defining a function in the shell's environment, but the shell still doesn't remember the command or its position in the shell's input stream after it's finished executing it.